# Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object: special characters in file names

Tags: vb.net, csv, datatable, oledbconnection, jet

I am creating a DataTable from a csv file and struggling with file names as they contain brackets and '#' characters. The code:

```
  CnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Me.TextBox2.Text & "\;Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"
  Dim tbl As New DataTable
  fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)
  s = "select * from [" & fn & "]"
  Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter(s, CnStr)
     Adp.Fill(tbl)
  End Using
```

It returns an error:

> Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object
>   '.W5000FLT.Wilshire 5000 Float Adjusted Index [M].csv'

But the actual file name (the value of 'fn') is

> ".W5000FLT#Wilshire 5000 Float Adjusted Index (M).csv"

As you can see, the Jet engine replaces '**#**' characters and **brackets** - from round to square.

Everything works fine with 'normal' file names.

Any suggestions how to get it fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce that exact error, but my version definitely can't handle the multiple brackets: `[file [x] name]`.  Maybe store the file name, change it, run your code, then change it back.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot change file names, because it will be  time consuming as there are 20K files automatically generated. It looks as special chars in file names is a common well known issue for Jet OLEDB. I have given up and changed the code to build DataTable manually using a classic StreamReader. Works perfectly fine with any file names and a lot faster.